# Pass Rails variable to AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement AJAX Upvote / Downvote on reviews of product (stackoverflow style).

I have a vote partial generated with each review:

_vote.html.erb

```
    <div id="vote_<%= review.id %>" class="vote">

      <%= link_to 'Vote Up', upvote_kata_review_path(@product, @review), :class => "upvote", :method => :post, :remote => true %>

      <span><%= review.plusminus %></span>  <!--show the current vote-->

      <%= link_to 'Vote Down', downvote_kata_review_path(@product, @review), :class => "downvote", :method => :post, :remote => true %>

    </div>
```

and an upvote.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#vote_id???').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'votes/vote' %>");
});
```

So when user clicks upvote, the partial will be re-rendered to show the new vote count.

The problem is, there are many reviews in a page. After the AJAX call, the JavaScript doesn't know which review's vote partial to re-render. (the $('#vote_id???') part)

Is there any way for Rails to pass the review id to the JavaScript?

Or any other alternative to implement this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to wrap upvote.js.erb in a document ready, because the document should already be ready by the time the AJAX request is triggered.

Comment: Please show us the code of the upvote action. You should ideally have a `@review` variable defined in it, which could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `@review` variable defined in the `upvote` action, like I suspect you might, then you can do this:

```
$('#vote_<%= @review.id %>').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'votes/vote' %>");
```

Comment: That works! Just curious - is this a good practice to pass variable like this?  and, is there a more elegant way to implement this voting functionality?

Comment: You're not really passing a variable here, you're just using what's made available to you through the request. The request routes to a URL which contains a `review_id` and inside your controller you're finding the matching review. Using it like you are doing is fine.

Comment: If the vote selector is defined within the partial, it is helpful to use jQuery's `replaceWith` rather than `html`.  While both would most likely work for the user, using `html` will leave behind extra elements.

Comment: So anything available in the controller is available in a .js.erb file.

Comment: Any instance variable defined in a controller's action is available in any template (be it a view or a partial) rendered by that action.